# Dealing with javascript undefined objects/arrays within an if statement

Tags: javascript

I am catching errors from an Ajax response. The kind of error that comes back depends on where it was thrown and I need to look out for certain ones.

I know the error variable always exists but past this I have to check the existence for each level, otherwise risk getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error.

I am currently doing:

```
if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.errors 
&& error.response.data.errors[0].title === 'no_space') {
   //do something
}
```

But there must be a better way?

Comment: just add another `&& error.response.data.errors[0] &&` ...

Comment: I think what you are looking for could be coming soon - optional chaining - https://dev.to/sammyisa/optional-chaining-may-be-coming-to-javascript--4ff0

Comment: _“But there must be a better way?”_ - why is this so convoluted in the first place? If you are in charge of the script that generates this structure in the first place, I’d maybe start by simplifying things there. `error.response.data.errors` seems rather redundant to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the keys and take the final value for a check.

```
var keys = ['response', 'data', 'errors', 0, 'title'];
if (keys.reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], error) === 'no_space') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I assume for this to work I would always need to know all the keys to get to the final value?

Comment: right, you need to know all keys in advance. what use case do you have?